# spring web flow: passing parameter from second flow to previous

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I have 2 flows. I want to go back to first flow from second when the user clicks on cancel, and I want to show the old content of flow 1. I'm trying to pass a value like this:

```
<view-state id="backHome" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:/home.do?homeId=oldHomeId" />
```

And from first flow. I'm trying to set the value to the view:

```
<input name="backHome" />
<on-start>
    <set name="requestScope.backHome" value="backHome" />
</on-start>
```

The value is not showing in jsp when I tried with: `${backHome}`

What is the proper way to load previous flow content when do a cancel from second flow? Any advice will be appreciated. :)

Comment: how are both flow linked? how do you go from flow 1 to flow 2?

Comment: please post more code samples

Comment: Is there a reason not to access flow 2 as a `<subflow-state>` in flow 1? It sounds like the behavior you want might be what that does.